# How to remove decimal points from dataframe column?

Tags: r, formatting

I've a `.csv` dataframe in which one of the columns is a `ZIP` code. The `ZIP` code is a factor. Here is an example:

```r
Country<- c("US","US","US","CAN","CAN")
ZIP<- C(00210,01210,65483.0,H3P,H3P3C)
data<- data.frame(Country,ZIP)
```

I did the following but the output is not what I want:

```r
data$ZIP<-round(as.numeric(as.character(data$ZIP)), 0)
```

Although it removed the decimals but now the zip code `00210`, `01210` became `210` and `1210`. Also, `zip` codes for `CANADA` became `NA`. I want to preserve the `zip` code numbers to `5` digit and preserve the `zip` codes of `CANADA`.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```r
data$ZIP <- sub("\\.\\d+$", "", data$ZIP)

#       Country   ZIP
# 1      US 00210
# 2      US 01210
# 3      US 65483
# 4     CAN   H3P
# 5     CAN H3P3C
```

## Explanation

From the help page, a typical usage of `sub` is

> `sub(pattern, replacement, x)`
>
> x is a character vector where matches are sought...

In our case `x`'ll be the `ZIP` column (values of the `ZIP` column to be specific).

The pattern  is `("\\.\\d+$")`:

`\\.` matches the `dot`

`\\d+` matches one or more numeric characters

`$` matches the end of the input string.

The replacement pattern is `""`.
It replaces numeric chars beginning  from a match of dot till the end with an empty string.

For example

```r
sub("\\.\\d+$", "", 21358.222)
# "21358"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, your edited code work. I also converted my zip variable from factor to character. For future understanding can you briefly explain or direct to some source on the use of this form "\\.\\d+$" in resolving this issue.

Comment: The help which can be accessed using`?sub` can give you info. I'll do an update if you want to understand how the `pattern` replaces the decimal with an empty string.